Where is the 'keyboard accelerator' setting in 24.04?
Before 24.04 I remember that I could enable the 'keyboard accelerator' in the system setting so that when I press the Alt key there will be an underline appears under the shortcut key:

However, I can no longer find this setting, and pressing the Alt key no longer works. How can I bring the underline key display back?
